# How can i maintain gap among textures while updating their position?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an array of coins which are falling downwards and when it comes down (y coordinate <0) I am updating y to a certain random integer which is causing overlap among textures.

inside constructor of GameState Class

```
for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        coins[i]= new Coin(i *(Coin.COIN_SPACING +Coin.COIN_WIDTH ),Game.HEIGHT/2 + i *(Coin.COIN_SPACING_VERTICAL +Coin.COIN_WIDTH));
    }
```

inside override update method

```
for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        coins[i].update(dt,score/SCORE_DIVIDENT);
        if(coins[i].collides(delta.getBounds())) {
            //coins[i].getTexture().dispose();
            score = score + 5;
            mScore = "Score:"+score;
            coins[i].playDropSound();
            coins[i].setPosition(new Vector3(coins[i].getPosition().x, coins[i].getPosition().y+MConstant.GALAXY_GRAND_PRIME_HEIGHT *2,0));
            coinCollided = true;
        }
    }
```

inside render override method

```
for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        sb.draw(coins[i].getTexture(),coins[i].getPosition().x, coins[i].getPosition().y);
    }
```

Comment: Where else do you use `coinCollided` flag? Also it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Screenshots would help to understand that.

Comment: What "overlap among textures" means? Are the coins on the screen overlapping or ...?

Comment: I feel like the question must be missing an explanation because it sounds like you're asking how to prevent respawning coins in random positions, and the answer is simply to not use random numbers when you respawn them.